Using IGBTs for controlling heating loads
I know traditionally antiparallel connected SCRs (Thyristors) are used in phase-angle control mode to control the heat delivered to an industrial furnace or to control heating loads. Can the same be achieved by using IGBTs in some configuration? Using IGBTs will help with lower EMI and lower reactive power (better power factor).
Could anyone share schematics or configurations that are commonly used in the industry for this purpose? I am trying to understand the working principles of power converters employing IGBTs for heating control.


Using IGBTs will help with lower EMI and lower reactive power (better power factor).

Not necessarily.  IGBTs are just another type of switch that can be turned on and off by its control terminal, whereas an SCR can only be turned on by its gate; an SCR cannot be turned off by its gate, turnoff is done by the external circuit that determines the current passing through the SCR main power terminals.
Quick summary:
A heater driver that needs the features of IGBTs may be constructed as a two-stage cascade of power converters; the output of the first feeds the input of the second, as follows:
Stage 1. An AC-DC converter.  This takes the AC supply and converts it into a stable, regulated DC voltage.  It must also present a good power factor to the AC supply, ie: it appears as a resistor to the AC supply.
Look up: "AC-DC converter with line current shaping".
Stage 2. A DC-DC converter.  This accepts the regulated DC output of stage 1, and converts this efficiently to the voltage required by the heater.
Look up: "DC-DC buck converter".
Detailed
The EMI and power factor will be mainly determined by the main power circuit & how it is controlled; the type of switch used (whether that be IGBT, MOSFET, BJT, SIT, SCR, etc), will have a lesser effect.
The control required depends on the application, and in particular these parameters:

The rate of temperature change when full voltage is applied to the heater (expressed as time to reach target temperature);
The temperature accuracy required;
The rate of change of the thermal load.

Case #1: Rate of temp change (RoTC) is slow: if it takes several minutes to reach target temperature when full voltage is applied, then you can use a simple on-off relay to regulate the heater.  This has low EMI & good power factor (assuming the heater is a pure resistance).
However, a faster means of control may be required in cases where the other two parameters are very onerous.
Case #2: If the RoTC is several seconds, then it is sufficient to switch whole cycles of mains AC supply voltage onto the heater at the zero-crossings.  SCRs are perfect for this role, and EMI and power factor will be slightly worse than case #1.
Case #3: When RoTC is shorter than case #2, then the switching times cannot be constrained to just the zero crossings, they must be allowed to occur anywhere within an AC cycle.  SCRs can be used, this is known as phase-angle control, but this will result in EMI & poor power factor unless mitigations are put in place.
Applying a smooth, adjustable DC voltage to the heater element gives the best control of the temperature; however if the power source is AC then an AC-DC converter is required.  Even if the power supply is constant DC voltage, we need an efficient means of converting that input voltage to the voltage required at the heater.  So a DC-DC converter is required.
Power converters, for AC-DC or DC-DC, require faster switching than what SCRs are capable of, and this is where IGBTs can be used to their full potential.

FYI, there are "gate turn-off" (GTO) SCRs. They are a bit difficult to use, which leads to the development of IGCTs and IGBTs. IGBTs being the easiest to use, which dominate for smaller applications; IGCTs are used at large scales (many MW).

@TimWilliams  Yes indeed.  And IGBTs were once called "COMFETs": COnductivity Modulated Field Effect Transistors.  :-)

Recently I had to develop a low-EMI heater control.
I simply used more heating elements, each element having lower power, and triacs to turn them on and off. Thus, at any moment, the only loads in the circuit are resistors. More power means more resistors in parallel, less power means less resistors. Power factor is ideal, there's very little EMI, and triacs are efficient and cheap. They need to be turned on right at the zero crossing to avoid EMI, and stay on for an integer number of whole periods to avoid DC current.
For fine grained control, one could use binary weighted resistors to make a few-bit "heating DAC". Using identical resistors, on the other hand, means they can be turned on in round robin order for more uniform heating.
Since this is a variable power space heater that uses excess photovoltaic production, one could even argue that triacs are 100% efficient in this use case...

Binary weighted resistive load... lovely!  :-)

I'm going to use it for the water heater too ;) It's a three phase resistor, so there are plenty of possible combinations!
